# Add portfolio link in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, tags, content-management-system, portfolio

I have this problem adding a link to my articles from the portfolio tag page.

Portfolio tagpage: http://aalborgflyttefirma.dk/portfolio/flyttefirma

Article http://aalborgflyttefirma.dk/portfolio/f%C3%A5-st%C3%B8tte-til-din-flytning

I can find this , but i dont know how to activate the url to the article there

Anybody can help?

Comment: How are you generating the portfolio page? Is it just a standard taxonomy page? If you generate this page with views, it should be quite simple.

Comment: Yes, it's just a standard taxonomy page.

Comment: Just enable the 'taxonomy term' view, this will override the default taxonomy term pages with the view and then you will have complete control of the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the following on the page where u want to make a link -
l(t('Link text'), 'about-us', array('attributes' => array('class' => array('about-link'))));

Comment: where does the input go?